Silent/background updates with Sparkle on macos
I am trying to have sparkle automatically download an install the update without any user intervention. I have set the following value in Info.plist
    <key>SUEnableAutomaticChecks</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SUScheduledCheckInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
    <key>SUAutomaticallyUpdate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SUAllowsAutomaticUpdates</key>
    <true/>

However, after the hour for the update period elapses, I see the popup showing that a new version is available.

Is there any additional configuration/code required to make this work?
The documentation states

In Sparkle 2, updates will be downloaded but not installed automatically if authorization is required. In all versions of Sparkle, if the application hasn’t quit for 1 week the user will be presented with installing the downloaded update (unless the updater delegate overrides this).

However, the app is in the Applications folder and Finder does not request additional permissions if I try to move the app to the Trash, so there's no reason for it no not install the update. The update is also just a zip (of the app) not a pkg file.

Answered here. The app was initially sandboxed, though the current build/updates weren't. It seems that

User defaults may not migrate cleanly if a sandboxed app becomes not
sandboxed

